# Create a copy of an AVPacket structure

Tags: c++, libavcodec

I'd like to make a copy of an AVPacket so that I can decode it later, when I like.

The AVPacket is from the audio stream.

av_dup_packet doesn't seem to work.

AVPacket copy constructor does not work.

Creating my own copy constructor causes memory corruption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to copy an AVPacket structure: (that works)

```
AVPacket newPacket(oldPacket);
newPacket->data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(new uint64_t[(oldPacket->size + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE)/sizeof(uint64_t) + 1]);
memcpy(newPacket->data, oldPacket->data, oldPacket->size);
```

The reason is that certain decoders use optimizations that require certain byte alignment and padding. Simply allocating oldPacket->size does not allocate enough neither does it allocate at a proper byte alignment.

Please note that this might not work for all cases, for instance if priv is set to something interesting.

Answer (score 2):

```
        AVPacket *newpacket = (AVPacket*)malloc(sizeof(struct AVPacket));
        av_init_packet(newpacket);
        av_packet_ref(newpacket, packet);

        av_packet_unref(packet);
        free(packet);
        packet = nil;
```

Since function av_dup_packet is deprecated from October 2015
[094952](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2015-October/094952.html)
 it is better to use instead av_packet_ref / av_packet_unref. 
New packet should be memory allocated and after initiated with av_init_packet

Comment: It would be nice if you added some description as to why this solves the problem

Comment: Wow, has it really been four years? Yeah, this could work since the memory management is handled by libav. Don't have the time to test though.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this approach:

```
AVPacket *clonedPacket = av_packet_clone(sourcePacket)
/* use clonedPacket */
av_packet_freee(&clonedPacket)
```

Comment: Yeah, the original question is 9 years old now. I hope things have progressed.