# How to write the same AVPacket to multiple outputs

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'd like to implement some sort of tee function using libav. I read packets from a file and would like to forward them to several output file.
So far, since av_interleaved_write_frame free the packet, I did this:

```
AVPacket pkt;
// Stuff to read packets into pkt

for (ic = 0; ic < nb_outputs; ic++) {
  AVPacket pkt2;
  av_copy_packet(&pkt2,&pkt);
  av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx[ic], &pkt2);
}
```

I wonder if it's the optimal way of doing it? 
Copying the packet seems overkill. I try to use av_packet_ref but it failed.

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929330/create-a-copy-of-an-avpacket-structure